# Matlab: labeling images stored in a single file based on image name

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was assigned a matlab assignment where I was given 25000 pictures of cats and dogs all stored in one folder. My question is how can I use the imagedatastore function on matlab to store these files into one single variable containing two labels (cats and dogs). Each image stored in the file follow the following format:
cat.1.png,
cat.2.png,
.....,
cat.N.png,
dog.1.png,
dog.2.png,
.....,
dog.N.png,

Ideally I think labeling them based on image name would probably be the best approach to this. How ever I've tired doing this using various implementations methods but I keep failing. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for both image data stores are the same:

1. Find all the image files with a matching name with `dir`.
2. Rebuild the full path to these files with `fullfile`.
3. Create the image data store with the files.

My code assumes that you are running the script in the same folder in which images are located. Here is the code:

```
cats = dir('cat.*.png');
files_cats = fullfile({cats.folder}.', {cats.name}.');
imds_cats = imageDatastore(files_cats);

dogs = dir('dog.*.png');
files_dogs = fullfile({dogs.folder}.', {dogs.name}.');
imds_dogs = imageDatastore(files_dogs);
```

You could also use the short path:

```
imds_cats = imageDatastore('cat.*.png');
imds_dogs = imageDatastore('dog.*.png');
```

If you want to use a single image data store and split files into categories within it (without using folder names, since all your files seem to be located in the same directory):

```
cats = dir('cat.*.png');
cats_labs = repmat({'Cat'},numel(cats),1);

dogs = dir('dog.*.png');
dogs_labs = repmat({'Dog'},numel(dogs),1);

labs = [cats_labs; dogs_labs];
imds = imageDatastore({'cat.*.png' 'dog.*.png'},'Labels',labs);
```

Comment: Is there anyway that instead of using 2 image data store variables (imds_cats & and imds_dogs) I could store it in just one but the separate the cats and dogs by category using the label property ?

Comment: Sure, but it's a little bit trickier. I added that code on the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Sure thing dude! :)